# Memory content mode

Tags: memory, operating-system

Is it correct that in memory program code is execute-only and data areas are read-write-only. Is this ever not the case?

Comment: You've actually got it the wrong way round - OSs don't distinguish between code and data. What made you think that this was the case, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: In a book I read about Base/Bounds Registers, so I perhaps they are not use with current OSs. Is'nt it?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually rarely the case, particularly if you are looking at mainstream operating systems such as Microsoft Windows, or Linux.

A very common attack vector for malware is a [buffer-overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), whereby a malicious attacker forces a program to write past the end of a data-structure, and overwrite program-code.

You can also write [self-modifying programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) that overwrite themselves with new code.

Answer (score 0):

In modern OS, W xor X is enabled by default. However, it's very easy to change page protection to allow both W and X.